# AndroId MediaPlayer error (1,-4) prepareAsync method

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've an error (1,-4) in prepareAsync method. The docs specify that this is a "not correct format of file" (right?) but the file is in mp3 format. In addition the same file was reproduced in an old version of the software when the mediaplayer was called in another Activity.
I don't know how solve the problem so here I am.

The code for the application is shown below:

**SingletonMediaPlayer** will manage a mediaplayer object used as singleton in application

```
public class SingletonMediaPlayer {

    private static SingletonMediaPlayer instance;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private int buffer_state;

    private SingletonMediaPlayer() {
        Log.d("SMP","Creating new media player");
        this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
        this.buffer_state = 0;
    }

    public static SingletonMediaPlayer getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonMediaPlayer();
        }

        return instance; 
    }

    public void play(String path, final TextView tv_messaging){             
        if(this.mp.isPlaying()){
            Log.d("SMP","Player is playing, now I'll stop and reset it");
            this.mp.stop();
            this.mp.reset();
            this.mp.release();
        }

        Log.d("SMP","Set audio stream type");
        this.mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {

            Log.d("SMP","Set data source");
            this.mp.setDataSource(path);
            Log.d("SMP","Prepare async");
            this.mp.prepareAsync();
            Log.d("SMP","Done!");
            tv_messaging.setText("Connecting to the server...please wait");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            tv_messaging.setText(e.toString());
            Log.e("SMP","IllegalArgumentException");
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            tv_messaging.setText(e.toString());
            Log.e("SMP","SecurityException");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            tv_messaging.setText(e.toString());
            Log.e("SMP","IllegalStateException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            tv_messaging.setText(e.toString());
            Log.e("SMP","IOException");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            tv_messaging.setText(e.toString());
            Log.e("SMP","Generic Exception");
        }
    }

    public void checkBufferState(final TextView tv_buffer_message){
        final SingletonMediaPlayer self = this;

        Log.d("SMP","  Set on prepared listener");
        this.mp.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

        });
        this.mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                OnBufferingUpdateListener lis = new OnBufferingUpdateListener(){
                    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mPlayer, int percent) {
                        Log.d("SMP","      Mediaplayer ready (preparation done). Inside buffer listener");
                        self.buffer_state = percent;
                        if(tv_buffer_message != null){
                            tv_buffer_message.setText(percent+"%");
                        }
                    }
                };

                Log.d("SMP","    Mediaplayer ready (preparation done). Installing buffer listener");
                mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(lis);
                Log.d("SMP","    Mediaplayer ready (preparation done). Starting reproduction");
                mPlayer.start();
                Log.d("SMP","    Mediaplayer ready (preparation done). Done!");
            }
        });
    }

    public int getBufferState(){
        return this.buffer_state;
    }
}
```

I'm creating buttons dinamically, when the button is clicked should play an mp3. So, just before the loop used to create buttons I have

```
final SingletonMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = SingletonMediaPlayer.getInstance();
mediaPlayer.checkBufferState(tv_sel_ep);
```

and than, for every button, I have

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.play(link, Text_view_used_to_show_error);
    }
});
```

**Log**

```
02-15 14:35:24.165: D/dalvikvm(1415): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 58K, 52% free 2633K/5379K, external 391K/517K, paused 87ms
02-15 14:35:25.705: D/NetworkActivity(1415): Starting SelectEpisodeActivity
02-15 14:35:25.995: D/SMP(1415): Creating new media player
02-15 14:35:26.005: D/SMP(1415):   Set on prepared listener
02-15 14:35:28.745: W/KeyCharacterMap(1415): No keyboard for id 0
02-15 14:35:28.745: W/KeyCharacterMap(1415): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-15 14:35:28.745: I/qqqqqqqqqqqqq(1415): qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
02-15 14:35:29.235: D/dalvikvm(1415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 307K, 53% free 2669K/5639K, external 477K/989K, paused 8ms+12ms
02-15 14:35:30.275: D/NetworkActivity(1415): Starting SelectEpisodeActivity
02-15 14:35:30.415: D/SMP(1415):   Set on prepared listener
02-15 14:35:32.485: D/SMP(1415): Set audio stream type
02-15 14:35:32.485: D/SMP(1415): Set data source
02-15 14:35:32.785: D/SMP(1415): Prepare async
02-15 14:35:32.785: D/SMP(1415): Done!
02-15 14:35:32.885: W/MediaPlayer(1415): info/warning (1, 26)
02-15 14:35:32.885: I/MediaPlayer(1415): Info (1,26)
02-15 14:35:32.885: E/MediaPlayer(1415): error (1, -4)
02-15 14:35:32.885: E/MediaPlayer(1415): Error (1,-4)
```

**EDIT: New log after Dave answer**

```
02-16 14:35:11.265: D/dalvikvm(12723): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 59K, 52% free 2633K/5379K, external 391K/517K, paused 133ms
02-16 14:35:13.265: D/NetworkActivity(12723): Starting SelectEpisodeActivity
02-16 14:35:13.405: D/SMP(12723): Creating new media player
02-16 14:35:13.415: D/SMP(12723):   Set on prepared listener
02-16 14:35:17.365: D/SMP(12723): Set audio stream type
02-16 14:35:17.365: D/SMP(12723): Set data source
02-16 14:35:17.435: D/SMP(12723): Prepare async
02-16 14:35:17.435: D/SMP(12723): Done!
02-16 14:35:17.445: W/MediaPlayer(12723): info/warning (1, 26)
02-16 14:35:17.445: E/MediaPlayer(12723): error (1, -4)
02-16 14:35:17.465: I/MediaPlayer(12723): Info (1,26)
02-16 14:35:17.465: E/MediaPlayer(12723): Error (1,-4)
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Couple things.

1) You should not call `release()` if you want the `MediaPlayer` to still be in a usable state afterward. The -4 error (if I remember correctly) is an invalid state transition, and trying to use a released `MediaPlayer` should produce exactly that error.

2) You can set the `onPrepared`, `onError`, and `onBufferingUpdate` listeners once when you create the `MediaPlayer`. What you are doing now seems awkward and unnecessary.

3) Post logcat output when you have an Android problem.

If you just do #1, you may end up with something workable. Setting the listeners before you actually use the methods that will call the callbacks is a good idea, though.

Edit:

```
private static SingletonMediaPlayer instance;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private int buffer_state;
// Add a member for the TextView
private TextView tv_buffer_message;

private SingletonMediaPlayer() {
    Log.d("SMP","Creating new media player");
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    Log.d("SMP","Set audio stream type");
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // YOU SHOULD REALLY DO SOMETHING HERE!!! IT COULD BE INFORMATIVE!!!
            return false;
        }
    });
    Log.d("SMP","  Installing buffer listener");
    mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener(){
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mPlayer, int percent) {
            Log.d("SMP","      Mediaplayer ready (preparation done). Inside buffer listener");
            buffer_state = percent;
            if(tv_buffer_message != null){
                tv_buffer_message.setText(percent+"%");
            }
        }
    };
    Log.d("SMP","  Set on prepared listener");
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
            Log.d("SMP","    Mediaplayer ready (preparation done). Starting reproduction");
            mPlayer.start();
            Log.d("SMP","    Mediaplayer ready (preparation done). Done!");
        }
    });
    buffer_state = 0;
}

// Remove the checkBufferState method and call the following in its place:
public setBufferMessageView(TextView tv) {
    tv_buffer_message = tv;
}

// getInstance, play, and getBufferState can stay the same, except remove the call to release
```

Comment: Well, I added the release() method when I was trying to solve the error by myself; if I remove it nothing change. I don't get the point 2, what is unnecessary? Point 3 you're right, I forgot the log when I posted the question.

Comment: If you were to simply add the listeners when you created the `MediaPlayer`, the entire `checkBufferState` method would be unnecessary. Notice in the log that the prepared listener is being set multiple times (that may be the problem, as the prepared callback calls start). I will edit my answer to illustrate what I believe would be better.

Comment: The prepared listener is set once, when I tested the application due to obtain the log file I've clicked on a button without link so was impossible to me reproduce the correct error. The string `02-15 14:35:28.745: I/qqqqqqqqqqqqq(1415): qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq` means something like `Physical return button pressed`. I correct my code with yours guideline but he still doesn't work (see the new log)